# jQuery: onkeypress, validación de formularios HTML

Tags: html5, jquery-validate

Estoy intentando la validación de un formulario el cual valide letra por letra ingresada en  un input HTML, mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
<html>
<head>
...
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var nombre;

    $("#nombre").keypress(function(){

        nombre=$("#nombre").val();
        if(nombre<3){
        $("#nombre-form-alert").css("display","block");
        }


    });
});

</script>
<head>
<body>
<form action='' method='' id='form-mp'>
...
<input type="text" id='nombre' name='nombre'><br>
<p class="form-alert" id="nombre-form-alert" style="display:none;color:red;"">Ingrese un nombre valido</p>
...
</form>
...
</html>
```

El problema es que nada mas el script funciona en el primer caracter ingresado y despues no hace nada, estube intentando usando un alert("caracter ingresado") despues de cada keypress.

saludos  !!

Comment: Es posible que el evento `onkeypress` no haya sido aplicado a tu input. Revisa las respuestas que la comunidad te ha brindado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es porque estas utilizando `keypress`, para la validación que quieres realizar debería ser `keyup`. Además la validación es incorrecta, para verificar la longitud de un texto debes utilizar `.length`. Prueba con el siguiente código:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var nombre;

$("#nombre").keyup(function(){
    nombre=$("#nombre").val();
    if(nombre.length<3){
    $("#nombre-form-alert").css("display","block");
    }
 else{
    $("#nombre-form-alert").css("display","none");
    }
});
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form action='' method='' id='form-mp'>

<input type="text" id='nombre' name='nombre'><br>
<p class="form-alert" id="nombre-form-alert" style="display:none;color:red;"">Ingrese un nombre valido</p>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te lo voy a mostrar con un ejemplo

tu codigo html :

```
 <input id="nombre" type="text" onkeypress="return validarSiNumero(event)"></input>
```

y en js:

```
 //Esto en caso de que nada mas quieras numeros
function validarSiNumero(e){
    var key = window.event ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if ((48 <= key && key <= 57) || (key == 0) || (key == 8)) 
     { return true; } else { return false; } // -
}

//Esto en caso de que nada mas quieras letras
function validarLETRA(s) { 
if (!/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/.test(s)) {
    alert("Este campo solo acepta letras");        
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo por la descripción de tu problema que necesitas validar el tamaño del nombre ingresado y mostrar el error si es menor a 3 caracteres. Si esto es así, te recomiendo que utilices keyup como se muestra a continuación. Igualmente, como recomendación, deberías agregar la validación antes de enviar el formulario al servidor utilizando

```
$('form').submit(function() { /* aqui validas */ })
```

Ejemplo de lo que necesitas:

```js
    $(function(){
       var nAlert = $('#nombre-form-alert');
       $('#nombre').keyup(function() {
         if($(this).val().length < 3)
           nAlert.show();
         else
           nAlert.hide();
       });
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Nombre :
<input type="text" id='nombre' name='nombre'><br>
<p class="form-alert" id="nombre-form-alert" style="display:none;color:red;"">Ingrese un nombre valido</p>
```

Answer (score -2):

No estás validando la longitud sin invocar el atributo length del objeto.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var nombre;

  $("#nombre").keyup(function(){
   nombre=$("#nombre").val();
   if(nombre.length < 3){
            $("#nombre-form-alert").css("display","block");
   } else {
           $("#nombre-form-alert").css("display","none");
      }


  });
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action='' method='' id='form-mp'>
    <input type="text" id='nombre' name='nombre'>
    <p class="form-alert" id="nombre-form-alert" style="display:none;color:red;">Ingrese un nombre valido</p>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```